# Flask app + celery task. Status always pending and not able to access celery app in cli

Tags: flask, celery

I am trying to learn celery on Flask app with Redis broker.

Here is my app.py:

```py
#Celery configuration
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

#Initialize Celery
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

#celery task
@celery.task(bind=True)
def long_task(self):
    """Background task that runs a long function with progress reports."""
    verb = ['Starting up', 'Booting', 'Repairing', 'Loading', 'Checking']
    adjective = ['master', 'radiant', 'silent', 'harmonic', 'fast']
    noun = ['solar array', 'particle reshaper', 'cosmic ray', 'orbiter', 'bit']
    message = ''
    total = random.randint(10, 50)
    for i in range(total):
        if not message or random.random() < 0.25:
            message = '{0} {1} {2}...'.format(random.choice(verb),
                                              random.choice(adjective),
                                              random.choice(noun))
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                          meta={'current': i, 'total': total,
                                'status': message})
        time.sleep(1)
    return {'current': 100, 'total': 100, 'status': 'Task completed!',
            'result': 42}


#Async task status
@app.route('/status/<task_id>')
def taskstatus(task_id):
    task = long_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
    if task.state == 'PENDING':
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'current': 0,
            'total': 1,
            'status': 'Pending...'
        }
    elif task.state != 'FAILURE':
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'current': task.info.get('current', 0),
            'total': task.info.get('total', 1),
            'status': task.info.get('status', '')
        }
        if 'result' in task.info:
            response['result'] = task.info['result']
    else:
        # something went wrong in the background job
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'current': 1,
            'total': 1,
            'status': str(task.info),  # this is the exception raised
        }
    return jsonify(response)


@app.route('/longtask', methods=['POST'])
def longtask():
    task = long_task.apply_async()
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('taskstatus',
                                                  task_id=task.id)}
```

I am following [this article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask/page/5) and [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-celery-example).

However, I encounter two issues:

1. The status of the task created is always shown as `Pending....`
2. I am unable to load my celery application as the 'app' module is not found

Here is the output when hit the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/status/<task-id>` route (I keep on getting this...):

```
{ "current": 0, "state": "PENDING", "status": "Pending...", "total": 1 }
```

And here is the output when I try to run celery on my app:

```
(my_venv) user_name@mac flask_celery % celery -A app worker -l info                                              
Error: 
Unable to load celery application.
The module app was not found.
```